# How to show the C# windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application developed in c#. This application send sms to client. This application was doing good till yesterday but suddenly this morning I find that if I start the application it is starting but not showing anywhere in the desktop not even in the task bar. I tried to stop it  using the Task manager but I could not find it in the task manager. I have included some function in my code which restricts to run two instances of this application at the same time. So, when I try to run again it shows this Application is already running. I can only close it using TCP Viewer which helps to close background program. But I have not written any line of code to run it on the background. 
Even when I am debugging it is going to the debug points correctly but not showing the form. Please help me on this.

Here is my form load code as sample:

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tcnt = 1;
        thistime = DateTime.Now.Date;
        techtime = "09:00:01";
        techdate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        dntime = DateTime.Now.Date;
        rebillingdate = DateTime.Now.Date;

        checkState[1] = true;
        checkState[2] = false;
        checkState[3] = false;

        this.tmrLog.Enabled = true;
        this.stStatus.Text = "Form loading";

        string myDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        string myFile = null;
        string myDir = "logs\\schedule\\";
        StreamReader sr = default(StreamReader);
        string str = null;

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(myDir);
        //DirectoryInfo DirItem = default(DirectoryInfo);
        FileInfo[] dirfiles = null;
        //FileInfo myf = default(FileInfo);
        this.Controls.Add(lsLog);
        lsLog.Items.Clear();

        if (dir.Exists == true)
        {
            foreach (var DirItem in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                dirfiles = DirItem.GetFiles();
                foreach (var myf in dirfiles)
                {
                    if (myf.Name.IndexOf("schedule") > 0 & myf.Name.IndexOf(myDate) > 0)
                    {
                        myFile = "logs\\schedule\\" + DirItem.Name + "\\" + myf.Name;

                        if (DirItem.Name == "48" | DirItem.Name == "IPX")
                        {

                            sr = File.OpenText(myFile);
                            while (sr.Peek() != -1)
                            {
                                str = sr.ReadLine();
                                lsLog.Items.Insert(0, str);

                            }
                            sr.Close();
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        tmrLog.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Comment: have you tried putting some break-points in and find out if it enters your code or not?

Comment: yes it enters inside the code correctly.

Comment: Did you check Visibility / Opacity properties of form?

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you used to restrict the second instance and the code which shown the form

Comment: Is InitializeComponent() method called from anywhere? What is value of ShowInTaskbar property of the form?

Comment: I would suggest to put the whole body of this code in the `Stack Code Review` then we can run and review it and let you know what's the problem